# FullScreen button not working - as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In my application, I am keeping so much of container with components. Now I have to create *Fullscreen* button for **VideoDisplay**. I tried some what like the followings

```
systemManager.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

And

```
this.stage.addChild(videoDisplay);
this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
videoDisplay.width = stage.width;
videoDisplay.height = stage.height;
```

But no use.
Is any other way is there to do it?

Comment: What part does not work? Is it not going to fullscreen or the video does not change it's size?

Comment: my whole application is going to fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is going to fullscreen but your video doesn't then you should probably resize it using size of your full screen:

```
videoDisplay.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
videoDisplay.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

But since your video will probably deform when adjusting to different screen dimensions (3:4, 9:16 etc) you should resize only one side and adjust the other like this:

```
videoDisplay.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
videoDisplay.scaleY = videoDisplay.scaleX;
```

Comment: If i did like this, VideoDisplay getting some what big size inside the container.

Comment: @user you're not posting enough code. What container? Do you have a stage listener to know when the screen becomes FullScreen/Standard and change video objects size?

Comment: I am working in a project. This project having more containers like groups. Inside a container I placed a VideoDisplay. So whenever I am getting the VideoDisplay X and Y value, It's giving 0 and 0. so I tried this too [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001538.html). But It's also not working. Now I am in helpless...

Answer (score 0):

Add the videodisplay object in a group and on fullscreen button click remove the video display from group and increase the group height and width according to screen resolution.

Then add the videodispaly object to the same group and set all the property like `height = 100%` `width = 100%` , etc

If its not working use videoplayer instead of videodisplay

Comment: I have to use only the VideoDisplay. That is my requirement.

Comment: then try to add the object in a group

Comment: I have to use **fullScreenSourceRect** or its not necessary.